# How do I DIY a spinning CD/DVD storage rack?

Tags: home-theater, electric-motor

I have an embarrassing number of dvd's and cd's; I think it's up to about 600 - 800 now... I have long ago started putting the majority in cd binders, but I have a really nice room dedicated as a library and I'd like to make the dvd's more accessable.

What I was thinking of was a podium that has a motorized spinner that could store all of the dvds in the body.  You could then scroll the entire catalog forward and backward to find what you want.

My carpentry is good enough that I could build the podium no problem, but I needed help on the guts... If there is a kit that someone knows of or has any ideas it would really help. [image: Here] I have included a (pretty terrible) sketch of what I had envisioned...

[EDIT] I'm adding links to [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqdSE.png) and [this Youtube demonstration](http://youtu.be/kahSNjcGodA) of what I believe this user to be referring to.

Comment: I had forgotten that some people still use these. So retro!

Comment: Yeah, I had thought of making the same podium and putting a media server in it and making a feux movie changer (where I could even burn the movie you wanted on the fly if you must have it as a dvd copy), but I have a lot of blu rays too... At least netflix can't bump the price of my dvd's and blu rays :)

Comment: You might be overthinking the problem ... I have shelves made from 1x6 boards & shelf brackets along the upper parts of my walls, that hold hundreds of DVDs. You get about 20 DVD cases per linear foot, and the shelves are 9" apart, so about 26 DVDs per sq.ft of wall space.  If I were going to build a cabinet, I'd still keep it simple, and do something like this : http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002ZQCFG4

Comment: So you want this thing to hold the dvd's like a book with an automated page turner? e.g. something that would solve this guy's problem? http://i.stack.imgur.com/h4gcO.jpg

Comment: **WARNING** make sure to take motion sickness pills before watching the linked video.  Somebody get that guy a tripod! Thank you @Aarthi for making me nauseous.

Comment: @BMitch, i was thinking of a page turner... and that is the most awesome picture I've ever seen...

Comment: @Rikon, that book is titled "Understanding Women" vol 1. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is "lazy susan hardware"

[image]

This will give you the spinning base you need to put your rotating shelves on.  I know Ace sells it, probably HD and Lowes do too.

A google search found a few examples of motorized lazy susan hardware - and some how to videos.

Comment: Or maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the question. ;)

Comment: Make sure the motor does not have too much power, or you'll be making a DVD chucking killing machine!

Comment: I dunno that could be fun too...